# Does COPPA restrict collecting city location from kids under 13?

Tags: coppa

The FTC states that "A home or other physical address including street name and name of a city" is considered personal information under COPPA.

Does that mean that city name alone is restricted as is street name + city? (i.e. is that statement a logical AND vs OR)

We are trying to give kids the ability to compare their sport speeds (i.e. running, sprinting etc.) to kids their own age in their city or the entire state. It seems odd that city is considered private information. We would like to store that a 9 year old in some city X sprinted at Y speed. It seems like it is benign information to store. If it is restricted, is there another way to store that data in a COPPA compliant way?